# DAX: Calculate differences between 2 years when value is not 0

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| NAME    | YEAR  | SCORE   |
+---------+-------+---------+
| A       |  2019 | 100     |
| B       |  2019 | 67      |
| C       |  2019 | 38      |
| A       |  2020 | 48      |
| B       |  2020 | 78      |
| C       |  2020 | 0       |
| A       |  2021 | 0       |
| B       |  2021 | 50      |
| C       |  2021 | 100     |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

I have a data table with structure below and I am trying to create a card which shows the difference between 2 years (current year - previous year) (which will be affected by Name slicer). However I couldnt seem get achieve below requirements. Is there any ways to achieve this?

1. if the score for previous year is 0, it will find the difference between current year - non 0 year. Example: if 2019 value is 0, it will find the difference between 2021- 2018.
2. if the current year is 0, it will compare the last 2 non 0 years. Example: 2021 value is 0, it will compare 2020-2019

Comment: What is current year? Year from Today? or selected Year in slicer? How names are related? can you show your related slicer and sample output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure like this

```
Measure =
VAR _tbl =
    TOPN ( 2, FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[SCORE] <> 0 ), 'Table'[YEAR], DESC )
VAR _yr1 =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[YEAR] ), _tbl )
VAR _score1 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[SCORE] ),
        FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[YEAR] ), 'Table'[YEAR] = _yr1 )
    )
VAR _yr2 =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[YEAR] ), _tbl )
VAR _score2 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[SCORE] ),
        FILTER ( VALUES ( 'Table'[YEAR] ), 'Table'[YEAR] = _yr2 )
    )
RETURN
    _score1 - _score2
```

which will give you this

[image: SA]

[image: SB]

[image: SC]